# How to generate SWF from FLA using command line on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a situation where I need to generate SWF from the FLA that user uploads on to the server. We use python and bash scripts, and work on Ubuntu Server 10.04 (64bit), any help on how to generate the SWF would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flash needs Flash IDE for compilation. 
You probably can compile code using flex AS3 compiler on linux, but if there are graphical elements in Flash, you cannot compile them.

However, we had a similar situation, which we fixed by installing Flash in a MAC OS X Snow Leopard(10.6) and then wrote some php, some shell script, some applescript and made a command line compilation mechanism for AS3.

Mac OS X is a unix based os, so the command line is similar to any other unix. it comes with built in php, so you don't have to install anything. 
Basically using script we dynamically generate something called .jsfl file. the jsfl contains the details of the .fla that needs to be compiled. these jsfl files can be executed by Flash IDE. so we invoke the flash IDE and pass on the generated .jsfl file. (http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2004/08/jsfl_fla_batch.html)

This gskinner process works in windows also, but using mac we can make it command line. so that users can just ssh to the mac and execute the command to build the file.

Answer (score 0):

FLA file format has changed significantly in the latest version of Flash. New FLAs are archives containing source files and assets, so you might be able to write a script unpacking a FLA and assembling an SWF from it. Prior versions of FLA contained proprietary format, not documented and there were no tools to process it in an automatic fashion, not on Linux for certain.

Depending on ActionScript version and your requirement to resource handling (by resources I mean images, fonts, sound tracks, videos etc) there are several options available:

1. Flex SDK, the material found in the blog post @ntidote refers to is somewhat dated, but it's OK / should work. You would need to consult MXMLC usage documentation to find out all available options (and some new required ones, not covered in the blog post). This is what you can do, if your goal is to compile AS3. This does not include video transcoding and you  might find it challenging to embed vector graphics. MXMLC is, however, capable of compiling a large subset of SVG. It can also compile FXG - a new interchange graphic format that can describe vector shapes and text.
2. ActionScript 2 can also be compiled, but Flex doesn't offer a compiler for that. There is a very good, in fact a much better than the one written by Adobe, compiler for AS2: http://tech.motion-twin.com/mtasc.html .

There are other tools that are capable of generating SWFs - all depends on what exactly you need to do. Here's a good collection of different utilities: http://www.swftools.org/

Haxe is a whole other programming language that can compile to SWF. It also has its own linkers and ways of managing resources. http://haxe.org/

There is this project, which allows you to compile complex vector graphics and even animations from XML descriptions: http://code.google.com/p/hxswfml/